# how dwarf format caculate provious sp pointer

Tags: assembly, stack, dwarf, stack-frame, stack-unwinding

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
this is example is from dwarf document.
How Can I caculate provious sp(r7) pointer,I mean It didnot save sp somewhere since sp is a callee-save register.

```
The architectural ABI committee specifies that the stack pointer (R7) is the
same as the CFA
```

what this means?
is this means "r7=cfa" , how come this is help to compute previous sp , and call a function may change sp.

In this example is that r8 is virtual? looks is a virtual.

dwarf pdf.

https://dwarfstd.org/doc/DWARF5.pdf
page 325

Comment: Generally speaking, you're looking to find out `fsize`, no?

Comment: It must restore `sp` for the caller but that doesn't mean it has to save it to memory, since it can be recomputed.

Comment: Nevertheless I find it puzzling why the `R7` column is filled with `s` (same value) all the way when clearly `R7` is changed twice. Also the comment saying `Start epilogue (R7 has been returned to entry value)` is obviously wrong, `R7` is only being restored later at the `add R7, R7, <fsize>`

Comment: yes,sp can be recomputed be compiler , But How debugger compute sp value base on dwarf info?

Comment: sp value can change when executing (call other functions will save caller-save registers and push extra argument on stack ). If I want to do backtracing means I want to restore sp in middle of executing .

Comment: Can you at least link the DWARF doc you're showing images of?  Pictures of text aren't good in Stack Overflow questions, but I realize it would be a lot of work to format the tables and code as markdown in a quote block.

Comment: Note that DWARF stack unwinding works by using separate metadata in the `.eh_frame` section of the ELF executable or shared library.  Not purely the architectural state; without separate metadata (to look up based on the current program counter), you need functions to always make frame pointers.

Comment: I just want to know the previous sp pointer at a executing point. I certainly can get this value just look at the table.

Comment: I think I cannot get information about this topic from elf.